# Retaining line weight when zooming in svgpanzoom

Tags: svg, svgpanzoom

As demonstrated in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/genworks/pen/EeJNMO?editors=1010

svgpanzoom increases line thickness proportionally to the zoom level, at least with default options e.g. when called like this:

```
var panZoomSVG1 = svgPanZoom('#svg-1', {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: true,
        fit: true,
        center: true});
```

Is there a way to have it retain the original line thickness even when zooming?

Comment: You can use this: `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` as presentational attribute in your SVG. Also you may add it in css: `path{vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;"}`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm (updated the pen to include it).

Answer (score 0):

enchaneta’s comment above answers the question exactly:

You can use this: `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` as presentational attribute in your SVG. Also you may add it in css: `path{vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;"}`